# How can I get the common digits of two int in C++? Example: (1234, 41567) --> 1 4

Tags: c++

Given two `int` I want to get all the common digits and print out them separated by spaces.

So for example, if `int x=1234; int y=41567;` then I want to print out: `1 4`.

This is my code. It does not work properly. When I run it, it prints `0 1 2 3 4 5` then stops.

I don't want to use vector nor arrays.

```
void problema3() {
    int x, y, kX=0, kY=0;
    cout << "x="; cin >> x;
    cout << "y="; cin >> y;
    int cx = x;
    int cy = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        kX = 0; 
        kY = 0;
        x = cx;
        y = cx;
        while (x != 0 || kX==0) {
            if (x % 10 == i) kX=1;
            x /= 10;
        }
        while (y != 0 || kY == 0) {
            if (y % 10 == i) kY=1;
            y /= 10;
        }
        if (kX == 1 && kY == 1) cout << i << ' ';
    }
 }


int main()
{
    problema3();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: And please learn how to *debug* your programs, like using a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: What happens if there is more than one occurrence of the common digit? E.g. 1223 and 224? Also, does the output order matter?

Answer (score 0):

**If** you're allowed to use `std::set` then you can do what you want as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void print(int x, int y)
{
    int individual_number1 = 0, individual_number2 = 0;
    
    std::set<int> myset;
    
    int savey = y;//this will be used to reset y when the 2nd do while loop finishes
  
    do 
    {
       individual_number1 = x % 10; 
      
       do 
       {
         individual_number2 = y % 10;
        
         if(individual_number1 == individual_number2)
         {
             myset.insert(individual_number1);
             break;
         }
         y = y / 10;
       }while( y > 0);
       
       y = savey;
       x = x / 10;
   } while (x > 0);
   
    //print out the element of the set
    for(int i: myset)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int x = 1234, y = 41567;
    
    print(x, y);
   
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is as follows:

```
1 4
```

which can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/wh5VwPgB7).

Answer (score 0):

Your main bug is when assigning copies of cy.

```
//...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //...
    x = cx;
    y = cx;    // <-- BUG!  should read y = cy;
```

But that's not the only bug in your program.

Your digit detection logic is wrong.  In particular, zero is not handled correctly, and since you did not put that reusable code in a function, your program is way more complex than it needs.

Here's the corrected logic for digit detection.

```
// checks if base 10 representation of a positive integer contains a certain digit (0-9)
bool hasDigit(int x, int d)
{
    do
    {
        if (x % 10 == d)
            return true;
        x /= 10;
    } while (x != 0); 
    return false; 
}
```

Your main loop then becomes:

```
// assuming int x, y as inputs.
// ...

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
{
    if (hasDigit(x, i) && hasDigit(y, i))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Which leaves very little room for bugs.

You can play with the code here: https://godbolt.org/z/5c5brEcEq